# PHP File Upload / move_uploaded_file Not Working

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload

I have the following form:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And the following script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";


    $moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/PHP_Ramp/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    if ($moved) {
        echo "Move: Success";
    }
    else {
        echo "Move Failed";
    }


      echo "Stored in: " . "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/PHP_Ramp/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }

else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

For some reason I keep getting "Move Failed".  Any idea why the file isn't moving?

======== SO thinks I need to explain this more; so I'm typing a sentence down here. ========

Comment: please include, while you're still typing, the full php error you see. This'll help a lot. Anyway; check if php safe mode is switched off (having it on and try to move uploaded files is probably the most common mistake made...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply giorgio.  I'm using notepad++ - how would I go about looking at the full php error?  I'm on IIS7.

Also - I verified that safe mode was off in php.ini.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check whether you have permissions in that folder `(C:/inetpub/wwwroot/PHP_Ramp/upload/`) to write file. You can check the folder by right clicking and selecting `properties -> Security`

Comment: I appended the following to the beginning of my code:

mkdir("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/PHP_Ramp/upload/", 0766);

and I'm still getting "move failed".

Comment: He means to make sure that the folder itself is writable by the PHP script. Adding 0766 is just modifying the moved file's permission once it's written.

Comment: The `mode` argument is ignored in Windows per http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php - I think @Shyju means NTFS permissions since @Mik said he's using IIS7.

Comment: Cool, I got it!  Just had to give write permission to IIS through right-click>properties>security.

Comment: Of course! Thank you. Linux systems man: `sudo chmod -R a+w directoryhere`